# Why do I get this url not found error? Unable to find the error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/codeigniter

ServerName localhost

ServerAlias localhost

<Directory /var/www/>

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

allow from all

</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/localhost.com-error_log

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/localhost.com-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

my config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In /var/www/codeigniter/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: still coundn't get anything in browser... what will the url will you plz say?

Comment: Is there any other file to cofigure .. am i missing anything bcoz i am new to codeigniter..

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about `CI`. Hope you get help from someone who know CI better.

Comment: clear your browsers cache. Set AllowOVerride none, remove the . htaccess file and use "FallBackResource /index.php" in your virtualhost and in virtualhost context.

Comment: Try `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/;`

Comment: Also, I think your RewriteRule should probably be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`